# Fatal error when pushing to GitHub

Tags: git, github, push

I am completley new to git. I am working on SL6 and created a file in the local repository. I have already created a remote repository on GitHub. I added a new file, and committed it, but I get the following error when I try to push to the repository

> error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing

any help would be great, especially if it has been idiot proofed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To definitely be able to login using https protocol, you should first set your authentication credential to the git Remote URI:

git remote set-url origin https://yourusername@github.com/user/repo.git
Then you'll be asked for a password when trying to git push.

In fact, this is on the http authentication format. You could set a password too:

[https://youruser:password@github.com/user/repo.git](https://youruser%3apassword@github.com/user/repo.git)
You should be aware that if you do this, your github password will be stored in plaintext in your .git directory, which is obviously undesirable.

so in such a way you won't get a 403 error

Comment: sorry! yes it did, there was a typo in my URL, many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You also can, if you don't want to deal with your GitHub user account password (by [encrypting a `_netrc` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309)), change the url of your remote to an ssh one.
See "[Generating SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)".

Then type (more in "[Changing a remote's URL](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url)"):

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:YourUserName/YourRepo
```

Comment: Thanks but again no joy

Comment: @user3588012 is it a repo you own? which is under your GitHub user account?